# is the azimuthal equidistant projection of the globe angle preserving

Tags: algebraic-topology, transformational-geometry

is the azimuthal equidistant projection of a sphere, the inverse of which takes the general point (x,y) to the point $$\bigg(\cos\left(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\right)\cdot\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}},\cos\left(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\right)\cdot\frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}},\sin\left(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\right)\bigg)$$
angle preserving?